# Python Tkinter canvas.delete failure

Tags: python, tkinter

In the experiment below, the tagbox Label should appear when I press the Button1, and it does. But if I follow that with a press on Button2, I get an error referencing a problem in the delete command of the disappear function, then referring to an "invalid boolean operator in tag search expression" in a tk module.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__()
        self.pack(fill=Y, side=LEFT)
        self.booking_canvas = Canvas(self, width=400, 
        height=100,background="red")
        self.button1 = Button(self.booking_canvas, text = "Appear", command = 
        self.appear)
        self.button2 = Button(self.booking_canvas, text="Disappear", 
        command=self.disappear)
        self.booking_canvas.create_window(20,10,window = self.button1)
        self.booking_canvas.create_window(80, 10, window=self.button2)
        self.booking_canvas.pack(side=LEFT)

     def appear(self):
        self.tagbox = Label(self.booking_canvas,text="Hello")
        self.booking_canvas.create_window(200,10,window = self.tagbox, anchor 
        = NW)

     def disappear(self):
      self.booking_canvas.delete(self.tagbox)

root = Tk()
MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Can you help? I'm not finding the error message very helfpul. I've been able to make the .delete method work in the simple examples I've found in the documentation, but not here.

Comment: Please include the actual error in your question. Also, the first argument to the delete method must be a tag or id but you're  passing in a reference to a widget.

Comment: I'm a Python newbie, still learning protocol. Should I include the entirety of the callback? They can get quite lengthy. And thanks for the solution, same as @falsetru pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code  should remember the return value of the `create_window()` call. Then pass it to `Canvas.delete` method:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    ...
    self.item = None

def appear(self):
    self.tagbox = Label(self.booking_canvas,text="Hello")
    self.disappear()  # remove old one
    self.item = self.booking_canvas.create_window(200, 10,
        window=self.tagbox, anchor=NW)

def disappear(self):
    if self.item:
        self.booking_canvas.delete(self.item)
```